# Drupal - Surround specific webform elements with a div

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-webform

as the title describes, I am to style a webform and for that i need to surround specific fields in divs in order to give them their CSS properties and I have no idea how I should go about doing that.

I've caught the form with hook_form_alter but no idea what to do after.

Any help?

Comment: You may have more luck posting this question to the link below as it is specifically for drupal :) http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: late to the party but isn't there any existing classes you can use to scope your styling. Furthermore, depending on your version of drupal/webform you can add wrapper classes in the admin area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your themes template.php file you need to get the forms ID and then you can do something like the following:

```
function phptemplate_webform_form_FORM_ID ($form) {
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="CLASS NAME">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  return _phptemplate_callback('webform_form_FORM_ID', array('form' => $form));
}
```

Replace FORM_ID with your form's ID.

**EDIT**

To add them for specific fields just do (something like) this:

```
$form['ELEMENT_NAME']['#prefix'] = '<div class="CLASS NAME">';
$form['ELEMENT_NAME']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

I've not got time to test it but replace ELEMENT_NAME with the element and that should solve your problem. There's a good page on it here - http://drupal.org/node/79086

Comment: yeah that *should* (didn't try it) add a div surrounding the form itself. But what i want to do is add divs surrounding specific fields in the form and also the submit button.

Comment: That wouldn't do it either as it would surround a specific element with a div whereas what I need is :

<div>
field1,2,3,4,5</div>
<div>
field6,7,8,9,10></div>

but anyway, not to bother you anymore, the Fieldset component works just fine. Ended up using that instead. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Ah I see. In that case I'd say go with Fieldset but you beat me to it.

Comment: Those should be `#prefix` and `#suffix`, otherwise Drupal will try to render them as an element not a property

Comment: Thanks Clive. I thought that might be the case. Edited to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use #field_prefix and #field_suffix to wrap field with any HTML element. See example below:

```
    function auworks_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
      switch($form_id) {
        case 'webform_client_form_1':
          $form['submitted']['title']['#field_suffix'] = '<span class="field-suffix">#</span>';
          break;
      }
    }
```

Let me know how you go...

Answer (score 0):

Additionally: in case you want to add containing div's to the *submit button* of the webform, here's a hook which will help you out:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form['#form_id'] === 'webform_client_form_YOURWEBFORMID') {
        $form_structure = &$form['submitted'];

        $form['actions']['submit']['#prefix'] = '<div class="extra_div">';
        $form['actions']['submit']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    }

}
```

If you want to apply this to *all* webforms, you just leave the conditional away, like this:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    $form_structure = &$form['submitted'];

    $form['actions']['submit']['#prefix'] = '<div class="extra_div">';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#suffix'] = '</div>';    
}
```